# Gui program not using WinMain entry point

Tags: c++, clang, msys2

I'm trying to follow the awesome Handmade Hero series but using clang in msys2. I set up a simple program to test out the compilation however I can't get it to use the WinMain entry point.

Here's the simple program

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    OutputDebugStringA(TEXT("hello console"));
    return 0;
}
    
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
    OutputDebugStringA(TEXT("hello windows"));
}
```

Using CodeLite the compiler/linker commands look like this:

```
C:/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++.exe  -c  "D:/Handmade/Handmade/main.cpp" -gdwarf-2 -fstandalone-debug -O0 -Wall   -o ../build-Debug/Handmade/main.cpp.o -IC:\msys64\clang64\include\c++\v1 -IC:\msys64\clang64\lib\clang\16\include -IC:\msys64\clang64\include  -I. -I.

C:/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++.exe -o ..\build-Debug\bin\Handmade.exe @../build-Debug/Handmade/ObjectsList.txt -L. -luser32 -Wl,-subsystem,windows
```

The code compiles without errors, but I see "hello console" when looking at DebugView. So WinMain is not being used as the entry point. I hoped -Wl,-subsystem,windows would make it use the gui subsystem but I guess not.

Is there a linker flag I'm missing?

Comment: This is exactly why you should make a [mcve] when asking questions here:  You have an extra function in your program that you don't want to use.  In the process of making the code minimal, you would have removed the function and solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike MSVC (which picks between `main()` and `WinMain()` based on the selected subsystem), MinGW accepts both options regardless of the subsystem (regardless of `-mwindows` flag).

It seems that `main()` has precedence over `WinMain()` if both are defined, and simply removing `main()` will make it prefer `WinMain()`.

---

If I recall correctly, MinGW provides a default `main()` that is a weak symbol, which calls `WinMain()`. So you either define `WinMain()` for it to call, or define `main()` which overrides the default.

This also explains why MinGW says `undefined reference to WinMain` if neither function is defined.